# Use Pandas to write JSON list to separate rows to sqlite3 db

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, sqlite

Imagine JSON that looks like this:

`[{"name": "foo", 'attr': ['bar', 'baz']}, {...}]`

I can easily read this into a DataFrame, no problem. (Python 3.9.2, Pandas 1.5.1)

If I just try it, I get `sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 2 - probably unsupported type.`, so it dies on the list type.

What I want to do is use to_sql() or something like it write to a normalized table, e.g.,

```
name attr
foo  bar
foo  baz
```

Is there an easy way of doing this? Also, I have full control over the production of the JSON, so if there is a better JSON format for Pandas, I can reshape the input file.

Comment: How are you reading the json into Dataframe?  The error generally occurs when you pass object (I suspect your list in `attr`) to dblite. Converting dtype to `str` for `attr` might help.

Comment: I'm just doing this:
    
`df = pd.DataFrame(data)`

where data is created by json.load(file).

Comment: Personally I think json format `[{"name": "foo", "attr": "bar"}, {"name": "foo", "attr": "baz"}, {...}]`  makes more sense. If you used this format, you could use `df = pd.json_normalize(my_json)` and from there on as your dtype would be string and export should work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood you correctly, you have multiple ways of achieving your goal.

## Method 1: Using your current JSON structure

First taking your approach, you have dict like this:

```
my_json = [{"name": "foo1", 'attr': ['bar1', 'baz1']}, {"name": "foo2", 'attr': ['bar2', 'baz2']}]
```

and you create a `pandas.DataFrame` object liket this:

```
import pandas as pd
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_json)
```

which gives you following:

```
   name          attr
0  foo1  [bar1, baz1]
1  foo2  [bar2, baz2]
```

now since `attr` column contains list, which is a object, it can not be exported as such to `sqlite` db. So we are going to have to either `explode` this column to have `my_df` in desired form. For this, we apply following function:

```
my_df = my_df.explode('attr').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Now our Dataframe looks like this:

```
   name  attr
0  foo1  bar1
1  foo1  baz1
2  foo2  bar2
3  foo2  baz2
```

all you need to do now is to export it to sqlite. For this we need an engine. I use `sqlachemy` to create one

```
my_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine('sqlite:///test.db')
my_df.to_sql("test_table_1", my_engine, if_exists="replace", index=False)
```

And now we have a table.

## Method 2: Different JSON Structure

Since you said you have control over structure of data, I personally like doing as less computing on service side as possible. So I think following JSON structure would be the best:

```
my_json2 = [
    {"name": "foo1", 'attr': 'bar1'},
    {"name": "foo1", 'attr': 'baz1'},
    {"name": "foo2", 'attr': 'bar2'},
    {"name": "foo2", 'attr': 'baz2'},
]
```

Downside of this is, the JSON size (i.e. number of lines) increases. But loading into df is straight forward.

```
my_df2 = pd.DataFrame(my_json2)
```

which gives me:

```
   name  attr
0  foo1  bar1
1  foo1  baz1
2  foo2  bar2
3  foo2  baz2
```

Now we can export in similar way as method 1,

```
my_df2.to_sql('test_table_2', my_engine, if_exists='replace', index=False)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed response and different choices. Excellent work. I think I will go with the second method, I agree about service side work.

Meantime, there is a third way, of course, which is to ignore Pandas altogether and just write the data using an sqlite cursor and a pair of for loops (outer over name, inner over attr). I still like your Method 2 better, but I thought I'd add this for posterity.